# Is there a way in Flutter dropdown_button2 version < 2.0.0 to customize the button and the dropdown separately?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter `dropdown_button2` version < `2.0.0`, I want to customize the button and the dropdown separately. Specifically, I want to give the button a fixed width, while letting the dropdown width expand and shrink to fit the text of the longest item in the dropdown. Please note that I'm using version `1.7.0`

I looked at version `2.0.0` and it's different. We can't use it. We need to keep using version `1.7.0`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by dynamically calculating the width of the drop down depending on the longest text in the drop down. Somethng like:

```
dropdownWidth: longestItemWidth > minItemWidth
              ? longestItemWidth
              : minItemWidth
```

I calculated the longestItemWidth by exracting the length of all items into an array and sortig it. Then I picked the last item in the array which will be the longest.